# Using python to find a sequence of bytes within a system dll in windows (ntdll.dll)

Tags: python, windows, dll, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to find a gadget that translates into `jmp esp` within the `ntdll.dll` windows DLL for my Reverse Engineering course, but am facing some technical issues.

I wrote the following script:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes, WinDLL


def GetModuleHandle(module):
    kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
    kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
    kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR]
    hMod = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(module)

    return hMod


def find_bytes_in_module(module_name: str, module_size: int, search_bytes: bytes) -> int:
    # Get the handle of the module
    hModule = GetModuleHandle(module_name)

    # Read the contents of the module into a ctypes array and convert to a bytes array
    ctypes_arr = ctypes.c_ubyte * module_size
    module_data = bytes(ctypes_arr.from_address(hModule))

    # Search for the wanted bytes in the module data
    index = module_data.find(search_bytes)

    return hModule + index


def main():
    module_name = 'ntdll.dll'
    module_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024  # ntdll.dll on my system is under 2 MB
    search_bytes = b'\xff\xe4'
    addr = find_bytes_in_module(module_name, module_size, search_bytes)
    print(f'`jmp esp` gadget found inside {module_name} at the absolute address: {hex(addr)}')

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The following code works when I run the commands inside `find_bytes_in_module` using a 64-bit ipython terminal, but due to my course limitations I am only allowed to use a 32-bit python interpreter.

When I try using any other distribution of python (I even tried a normal 64 bit python interpreter) to run this script, it crashes on the line `module_data = bytes(ctypes_arr.from_address(hModule))` . Specifically when trying to convert the ctypes array into a bytes array.

Exit code is `-1073741819`. I tried running the terminal with administrator rights and I got the same results.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Maybe this isn't even the direction I should be taking (I am trying to find the offset from the beginning of the dll to the gadget)
I am using a 64-bit windows 10 distribution, in case it matters (hopefully it shouldn't).

Edit: I found on google that this error code means that an Access Violation exception occured in the context of the program's main thread and was not caught by the program's code, thus causing the program's main() / WinMain() entry point to exit prematurely, terminating the process. However, I don't know what I should have done differently to prevent this, and why it didn't happen when I did the very same thing interactively in iPython...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, I also tried with the current size of module, since the size you passed is a bit bigger than the module size I got on an up to date windows 10,  but I also got the same interpreter crash...

Solved it easily by using `ReadProcessMemory` instead. The code is quite simple:

- Get module HANDLE by calling [`GetModuleHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew).
- Get module size by calling [`GetModuleInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation).
- Read module by calling [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory).

This obviously works as long as the module is loaded into the process address space.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes as wt

# Windows Structs


class MODULEINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('lpBaseOfDll', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('SizeOfImage', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('EntryPoint', ctypes.c_void_p)
    )

# Windows API


kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
GetModuleHandle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetModuleHandle.restype = wt.HMODULE
GetModuleHandle.argtypes = (wt.LPCWSTR, )

ReadProcessMemory = kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = (
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # HANDLE hProcess
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # LPCVOID lpBaseAddress
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # LPVOID  lpBuffer
    ctypes.c_size_t,  # SIZE_T  nSize
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)  # SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesRead
)
ReadProcessMemory.restype = wt.BOOL

psapi = ctypes.WinDLL("psapi", use_last_error=True)
GetModuleInformation = psapi.GetModuleInformation
GetModuleInformation.restype = wt.BOOL
GetModuleInformation.argtypes = (
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # HANDLE hProcess
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # HMODULE hModule
    ctypes.POINTER(MODULEINFO),  # LPMODULEINFO lpModinfo
    ctypes.c_uint32,  # cb
)


def get_module_info(h_module) -> MODULEINFO:
    """Get Module information for a module loaded into the python interpreter address space.

    Args:
        h_module: The HMODULE (module base address) to the module for which to get the information.

    Returns:
        An instance of the MODULEINFO structure.
    """
    h_current_proc = ctypes.c_void_p(-1)  # pseudo handle to current process.
    module_info = MODULEINFO()
    ret_val = GetModuleInformation(h_current_proc, h_module, ctypes.byref(module_info), ctypes.sizeof(module_info))
    if ret_val == 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return module_info


def read_module(base_addr: int, size: int) -> bytes:
    """Read the entirety of a module loaded in the Python interpreter.

    Args:
        base_addr: base address of the module to read.
        size: Size of the module.

    Returns:
        A bytes instance containing the bytes read from the module.
    """
    h_current_proc = ctypes.c_void_p(-1)  # pseudo handle to current process.

    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'', size)
    nobr = ctypes.c_size_t(0)
    ret_val = ReadProcessMemory(h_current_proc, base_addr, buffer, size, ctypes.byref(nobr))
    if not ret_val and ctypes.get_last_error() != 299:  # ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY
        raise ctypes.WinError()
    return buffer.raw[:nobr.value]


def find_bytes_in_module(module_name: str, search_bytes: bytes) -> int:
    # Get the handle of the module
    h_module = GetModuleHandle(module_name)
    if h_module == 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    module_info = get_module_info(h_module)
    print(f"{module_name}: Base: {module_info.lpBaseOfDll:#016x}; Image Size: {module_info.SizeOfImage:#016x}")

    # Read the contents of the module into a ctypes array and convert to a bytes array
    module_data = read_module(h_module, module_info.SizeOfImage)

    # Search for the wanted bytes in the module data
    index = module_data.find(search_bytes)
    if index == -1:
        # oops, pattern not found...
        return -1

    return h_module + index


def main():
    module_name = 'ntdll.dll'
    search_bytes = b'\xff\xe4'

    # no need to load ntdll, it's already in the process address space.
    addr = find_bytes_in_module(module_name, search_bytes)
    if addr < 0:
        print("Could not find the pattern in the module.")
        return 0

    print(f'`jmp esp` gadget found inside {module_name} at the absolute address: {addr:#016x}')

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```